# "Good version" of the word jobsworth

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a good version of the word jobsworth?

Someone who is hardworking, dedicated, good team worker but not a complete tool about it?

**Edit.**

By way of background, for Americans who may not have encountered this word, the OED defines ***jobsworth*** as: *a person in authority (esp.a minor official) who insists on adhering to rules and regulations or bureaucratic procedures even at the expense of common sense*.

It derives from the expression *It's more than my job's worth to let you do that*. The TV programme *That's Life* hosted by Esther Rantzen in the 1970s, used to award a jewel-encrusted peak cap to the official who had attempted to enforce the most stupid rule - called the *jobsworth of the week award*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the various definition that I've read so far, ***[jobsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jobsworth)*** seems to have negative connotations. I am of the opinion that the person complicates things and causes widespread nuisance. I even found "[Little Hitler](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/little-hitler)" to be synonymous to it!

Even though I don't have an equally quirky term, if my understanding is correct, a term with a positive connotation could be :

***[forthright](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forthright)***

> honest and direct : providing answers or information in a very clear and direct way

[Merriam-Webster]

If you think *forthright* sounds archaic, you can replace it with "***straightforward***", "***undemanding***" , "***uncomplicated***"  , "***frank***" and the likes. All these words have a positive to neutral connotation depending on your context.

#### Side Note

If you are a fan of social media memes, I'd say **jobsworth** is best represented by [***Scumbag Steve***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Scumbag+Steve) and someone who is just ***straightforward*** could be the [***Good Guy Greg***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Good+Guy+Greg)! However, this is rather informal and if you choose to use it in your context, proceed with caution.