# A word like Bossy-Boots

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who tries to enforce rules without any authority? I will accept similar definitions etc.

For example, I live in a gated community and if anyone does anything, like parks a car in the wrong place or looks after a friend's dog for the day (where no dog's allowed) this lady will come and tell you off irrespective of the fact she has no authority to do so.

I've heard people use Nazi or Gestapo... any other suggestions?

Comment: She's an [***uberfraulein***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=uberfraulein&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) in [***Hitler's grannies***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22hitler%27s+grannies%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) Or just an *interfering ole bag* in the modern parlance.

Comment: Closely related- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/303861/good-version-of-the-word-jobsworth . I learnt about "little hitler" there.

Comment: Translating slang to colloquialism by way of *argot* is a messy business.  It would help to know where you and your noisome neighbor live. "Mrs. Grundy" would do in some circles, while a plainspoken synonym for the extreme nether end of an equine's digestive tract might suit in others.

Comment: haha cheers guys. I'm in brisbane, Australia

Comment: The character Gladys Kravitz from the old US television show, *Bewitched*, comes to mind. You can just call her *Mrs. Kravitz*, and she'll have no idea what you're talking about. :)  But in all seriousness, I tend to call people like that **busybodies** because they don't seem to have enough important things in their own life to keep from butting in to everyone else's.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Pearce

Comment: You could say "She thinks she's the queen bee".

Answer (score 1):

**Scofflaw**....sorry, that would be you.  **Nosy-parker**... **Busybody**...

Answer (score 0):

There is the term 'Little Napoleon'.

I can't find a decent citation as it always seems to be conflated with ['Napoleon Complex'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon_complex) (Source *www.wikipedia.org*), but I am certain I have heard it used in relation to a person that overcompensates for some perceived shortcoming (no pun intended) not necessarily just shortness of stature. In this case it could be their perceived impotence to force others to conform to the rules they hold so dear.

Comment: cheers, thats a good one

Answer (score -1):

I would call her a **dragon**. It is defined in dictionary as a very watchful and strict woman.

[image]